# Idiom or phrase to describe the worst of two situations

Tags: phrase-usage, idiomatic-language

Is there any idiom or phrase to describe a bad situation which is worse than another bad situation.

Scenario, between **robbery** and **robbery with an infliction of injury**. Robbery with an infliction of injury is indeed worse than a mere robbery. I am thinking of the phrase **the worst of its range**. But i dnt know whether it suits the context of the sentence below.

> Given the circumstances, robbery with an infliction of injury is **the worst of its range**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One particular turn of phrase that's [become increasingly popular](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=is%20the%20absolute%20pits&year_start=1920&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) in my lifetime is...

[image]

> [***the (absolute) pits***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/the%20pits#:%7E:text=informal,weather%20is%20the%20absolute%20pits.)
> informal
> *something that is very bad or unpleasant*

---

I've generally found [TheWordDetective](http://www.word-detective.com/2008/08/pits-the/#:%7E:text=From%20originally%20meaning%20literally%20%E2%80%9Cstinky,describe%20anything%20that%20metaphorically%20stinks.&text=The%20pit%20man%20got%20all,a%20bad%20job%20or%20experince.) to be a reliable source of background information on various idiomatic usages, so I'm inclined to believe them as regards the origin of this particular one...

> *The use of “**the pits**” to mean the worst and most unpleasant instance of something, however, has its source a bit closer to home* [than **pit=hole in the ground**]. *“**Pits**” in this sense is simply short for “**armpits**,” long considered an unpleasantly aromatic region of the human body.*

Answer (score 2):

One possibility that comes to my mind is "the worst of the worst".

So your sentence might be:

> "Given the circumstances, robbery with an infliction of injury is the
> worst of the worst."